# Sqlalchemy order_by custom ordering?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a `state` column in my table which has the following possible values: `discharged`, `in process` and `None`.

Can I fetch all the records in the following order: `in process`, `discharged` followed by `None`?

Answer (score 2):

If you've declared that column as an enum type (as you should for cases such as these where the values are drawn from a small, fixed set of strings), then using `ORDER BY` on that column will order results according to the order in which the values of the enum were declared.  So the datatype for that column should be `ENUM('in process', 'discharged', 'None')`; that will cause `ORDER BY` to sort in the order you desire.  Specifically, each value in an enum is assigned a numerical index and that index is used when comparing enum values for sorting purposes.  (The exact way in which you should declare an enum will vary according to which type of backend you're using.)

Comment: Is that enum function part of slqlachmey, python or sql?

Comment: Sometimes using strings instead of enums bypasses some intermediate steps, especially when printing pretty strings.

Comment: It's part of SQL; it's a datatype that you use when declaring your schema, like `VARCHAR`.  SQLAlchemy is aware of that type, just as it's aware of the other basic types, and it has a builtin [class that maps to it](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html?highlight=enum#sqlalchemy.types.Enum).